# Can't install Sims 3 purchased from GameStop on Steam?

Tags: steam, the-sims-3

I have bought the Sims 3 (and some expansions) discs from GameStop, and I'd like to buy the Sims 3 Seasons from Steam.

However Steam won't let me download the game because I don't have the Sims 3 installed on Steam.

Is there any way I could install the Sims 3 onto Steam without rebuying it?

Comment: You might be able to activate the game on Origin, EA's version of Steam. If so then you can buy the expansion directly from EA through Origin.

Answer (score 2):

**According to the [list of supported retail games on Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601), you can not activate The Sims 3 with Steam, if you have purchased it from a retail store.**

Some games are accepted, some games are not. As it is, I have found a few forum posts, complaining about how unreliable Sims 3 keys can be, while finding sources for this answer. One user reported not needing a key to play, but not being able to activate their key with the EA, themselves. This may have something to do with it; Valve would be hesitant to honour a CD key where even the developers appear to have issues identifying legitimacy.

This is also confirmed on the [Steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/47890/discussions/0/864946409135205406/), and on [Yahoo! Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120308133408AAN2YIG).

Answer (score 0):

This feature that you're looking for is available within Steam.

However it's only for [some games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601) and unfortunately The Sims 3 is not one of them.

So **there is no way to do what you are trying to do**.

Your only options are to;

- Buy the game again through Steam
- Continue buying them from GameStop (or another retail shop)

Comment: Generally speaking it only works with retail boxed games that include a Steam key needed to activate the game on Steam in order to play it. So if you have retail boxed copy of a game that you can play without Steam, you probably can't add it to your Steam library without buying a second copy.

Comment: @RossRidge, this is not true. There are many games that do not need Steam to play. This is why they have a list of compatible retail games. I personally have quite a few games that I activated with Steam years after my original purchase and play through. In my experience, retail games that still require Steam are much rarer then games that simply support it.

Comment: @Timelord64 Most of the games on the list are Steam only games. There are a number of exceptions, but the fact that many of the key formats are the same is not a coincidence. They're the format used by Steam keys.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, most, but not all.

Comment: @Timelord64 I never said all.